# How to get opt group values in bootstrap-multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

```
var data = [
 {
  "label": "WKS-FINGER1",
  "children": [
   {
    "label": "WKS1",
    "value": "WKS1"
   },
   {
    "label": "WKS2",
    "value": "WKS2"
   },
   {
    "label": "WKS2",
    "value": "WKS2"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "label": "WKS-FINGER",
  "children": [
   {
    "label": "WKS3",
    "value": "WKS3"
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "label": "WKS-FINGER2",
  "children": [
   {
    "label": "WKS4",
    "value": "WKS4"
   }
  ]
 }
];

$('#myid').multiselect({
             enableClickableOptGroups: true,
             buttonWidth: '200px',
             onChange: function(option, checked, selected,element) {

                var selectionData = [];
                     $('#myid option:selected').each(function() {

                         selectionData.push([$(this).val() , $(this).data('order') ]);
                }); 
                     alert(selectionData);

 }
         });
                      $('#myid').multiselect('dataprovider', data);
```

As per the above code I am able to get the option values from drop down but how to get the values of the selected groups also when any value is selected.  For eg . if somebody selects `WKS-FINGER1` group I need its group value `WKS-FINGER1` and not the option value and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Nofiden/b8wsxr89/4/)

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
<body>
     <div id="multiselection">
     <select id="myid" multiple="multiple">
     </select></div>
     <span id="output"></span>

</body>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(function() {
                var data = [{
                    "label": "WKS-FINGER1",
                    "children": [{
                        "label": "WKS1",
                        "value": "WKS1"
                    }, {
                        "label": "WKS2",
                        "value": "WKS2"
                    }]
                }, {
                    "label": "WKS-FINGER",
                    "children": [{
                        "label": "WKS3",
                        "value": "WKS3"
                    }]
                }, {
                    "label": "WKS-FINGER2",
                    "children": [{
                        "label": "WKS4",
                        "value": "WKS4"
                    }]
                }];

                $('#myid').multiselect({
                    enableClickableOptGroups: true,
                    buttonWidth: '200px',

                    onChange: function(option, checked, selected, element) {

                        var temp = jQuery.extend(true, {}, newData);

                        var selectionData = [];
                        var selectionGroup = [];
                        $('#myid option:selected').each(function(e) {
                            for (n in newData) {
                                for (d in newData[n]) {
                                    if (newData[n][d].value == $(this).val()) {
                                        for (i in temp[n]) {
                                            if (temp[n][i].value == $(this).val())
                                                temp[n].splice(i, 1);
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            selectionData.push($(this).val());
                        });

                        for (t in temp) {
                            if (temp[t].length == 0) {
                                selectionGroup.push(t);
                            } else {
                                for (tt in newData[t]) {
                                    if (newData[t][tt] == temp[t][tt]) {
                                        selectionData.push(newData[t][tt]["value"]);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        console.log("Group : " + selectionGroup);
                        console.log("Data : " + selectionData);
                        $("#output").html("Group : " + selectionGroup + "<br>Data : " + selectionData);
                        //alert("Group : " + selectionGroup + "\nData : " +selectionData);

                    }
                });
                var newData = {};
                $('#myid').multiselect('dataprovider', data);
                var clonedData = jQuery.extend(true, {}, data);
                for (i in clonedData) {
                    newData[clonedData[i]["label"]] = clonedData[i]["children"];
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: thanks it works for me.
why group label not having checkbox

Comment: This is extremely under-rated. +1

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check the last example in the Further Examples section of the [documentation](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#further-examples) (scroll down to the last example in this section). This example restricts the number of selected options within a specific group of options. In the `onChange` option, the option group is derived from the changed option(s) - this is the interesting part for you to deriv the option group label from the clicked/changed option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-optgroup-limit').multiselect({
            onChange: function(options, checked) {
                var $option = $(options);
                // This example works onyl for selection one option a time, has to be adapted to your case ...
                if ($option.length == 1) {
                    // This is the important part for you: get the parent optgroup:
                    var $group = $option.parent('optgroup')
                    // Here, the properties of the optgroup can be checked ... 
                    if ($group.hasClass('group-1')) {
                        var $options = $('option', $group);
                        $options = $options.filter(':selected');

                        if (checked && $options.length > 2) {
                            alert('Cannot select more than 2 elements in this group!');
                            $("#example-optgroup-limit").multiselect('deselect', $option.val());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
       });
    });
</script>
<div class="btn-group">
    <select id="example-optgroup-limit" multiple="multiple">
        <optgroup class="group-1" label="Group 1">
            <option value="1-1">Option 1.1</option>
            <option value="1-2">Option 1.2</option>
            <option value="1-3">Option 1.3</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup class="group-2" label="Group 2">
            <option value="2-1">Option 2.1</option>
            <option value="2-2">Option 2.2</option>
            <option value="2-3">Option 2.3</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

You can adapt the example to query `$group.attr('label')` instead of the class and replace the remaining code with whatever you want to do with the group's label you just derived from the clicked option(s).

Comment: As per the documentation `enableClickableOptGroups: true` should give a check box to groups in drop down box but as per the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nofiden/b8wsxr89/4/) I am not getting the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly you need to access parent options group inside onChange callback as described in the [documentation](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#further-examples):

```
var $option = $(option);
var $group = $option.parent('optgroup');
alert($group[0].label);
```

See the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/b8wsxr89/)

Comment: Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8wsxr89/1/) I should be able to get the get the group when the group is selected and I need to maintain a data set that keeps the values of only selected datasets.